# combine strings into a instance name: Actionscript 2/Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I want to combine strings to use it in following script.

```
    var x = 2;
    "Shoot"+x._x += 50;
```

this work: `Shoot2._x+= 50;` but I have more then two Shoots

how do I combine them, that I can use `._x` on my "Shoot2" instance of a movieclip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using :

```
this['Shoot' + x]._x += 50;
```

or

```
eval('Shoot' + x)._x += 50;
```

or `setProperty()` to set a value :

```
setProperty(eval('Shoot' + x), _x, 50);
```

For more about that, take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7f8a.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: thanks, this work for me
`eval('Shoot' + x)._x += 50;`